# Running cgroups inside EC2 c4.xlarge instances failed - operation not allowed

Tags: debian, systemd, amazon-ec2, cgroups

## Problem

I'm currently trying to restrict the resource of of a specific user on an AWS EC2 instance. After doing some research online, I thought the following was enough to add a user to a cgroup that limits memory:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cgroup-bin cgroup-lite libcgroup1
$ cgcreate -a root -t ray_zhang -g memory:limitgroup
cgcreate: can't create cgroup limitgroup: Cgroup, operation not allowed
```

I searched up the error message but was unable to find anything substantive. I am running as `root`, and I am trying to restrict the user `ray_zhang` from utilizing 100% memory.

I have also tried to modify `cgrules.conf` and `cgconfig.conf` in `/etc` but could not observe the memory limiting. I did the following:

```
/etc$ cat cgrules.conf
ray_zhang   memory  memlimit/
/etc$ cat cgconfig.conf
group memlimit {
     memory {
         memory.limit_in_bytes = 1024m;
     }
}
```

And to test I did the following (in the user `ray_zhang` via `sudo su ray_zhang`):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul 18 2016, 15:02:52)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = ' '*3000000000
```

On htop I saw it used roughly 3GB of RAM which means the 1024m restriction was not respected.

### Attempts

Another attempt was using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557843/looking-for-a-consistent-way-to-configure-cgroups-on-ubuntu-14-04-desktop)
. Following the instructions and running the same python test, the memory was once again not limited and I observed in:

```
$ cat /var/log/cgrulesengd.log | grep python
Cgroup change for PID: 22745, UID: 16975, GID: 996, PROCNAME: /usr/bin/python2.7 FAILED! (Error Code: 50002)
```

### Environment

I am running on a fairly old OS version for debian:

```
/etc$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
/etc$ uname -a
Linux <redacted> 4.4.0-154-generic #181~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 25 16:40:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But I also tried to do this inside of a docker container with Ubuntu 18.04 inside this instance and it still failed with the same `Cgroup, operation not allowed` error.

#### Extra

One of my suspicions is that **there are issues with cgroups inside of virtualized environments. Since I'm running in EC2, that means I'm probably operating inside of a VM or a container. Perhaps that is blocking me from using cgroups?**

I also saw forums online using `cgred` on `systemd`, but it seems to not have installed for me upon installing those 3 from `apt-get`:

```
/etc$ which cgred
/etc$ sudo service cgred start
cgred: unrecognized service
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should start with trivial checks bypassing libcgroup - check that `/sys/fs/cgroup/*` mounts are `rw`; try creating cgroups manually using `mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/limitgroup`, etc.